# SQL Server stored procedure(Need recent 5 months onlly)

Tags: sql-server

I need to track visitors on my site, So i am using this stored procedure, But its not giving me the desired result , can anyone help me out.
I need January at last..... i mean after december

```
Select A.TotalPerMonth , DateName( month , DateAdd( month , A.monthValue , -1 ) ) as month , A.Year 
from(Select Top 5 count(pk_id) as TotalPerMonth,
 month(VistorDate) as monthValue,
 Year(VistorDate) as Year 
 from jot.tbl_vistor 
 group by  month(VistorDate) ,YEAR((VistorDate))
 order by  YEAR((VistorDate)) desc) A order by A.monthValue  , A.Year ASC
```

Following is the result, I need the january month at last but is giving me at the front

[image]

Here is my table[image]

**Description Desired** :
 **i need top 5  sep, oct, nov , dec , jan ..... means last 5 month , when new record fabruary is found , it will discard sep**

Comment: @tinka after using this , I have no value of december , but january is at last , i do Select top 5

Comment: You should give a better description of what your desired result is.. Give us an example of the correct order.

Comment: i edit the question , who is damn downvoter

Comment: What is the logic of sep at top, followed by oct, nov an dec?

Comment: Sir i need recent 5 month , so if we have entry of the Feb month, 
1.oct
2.nov
3.dec
4.jan
5.feb

Comment: @MangalPardeshi ,, i hope u getting me

Comment: @JotDhaliwal, did you see lad2025's answer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear, but I think you want this:

```
SELECT  A.TotalPerMonth ,
        DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, A.monthValue, -1)) AS month ,
        A.Year
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 5
                    COUNT(pk_id) AS TotalPerMonth ,
                    MONTH(VistorDate) AS monthValue ,
                    YEAR(VistorDate) AS Year
          FROM      jot.tbl_vistor
          GROUP BY  MONTH(VistorDate) ,
                    YEAR(( VistorDate ))
          ORDER BY  YEAR(( VistorDate )) DESC ,
                    MONTH(VistorDate) DESC
        ) A
ORDER BY A.Year ,
         A.monthValue
```

I.e. in subquery you ordering by year desc and month desc to get last 5 months. In outer query you ordering by year asc and month asc.

Comment: @JotDhaliwal, you were wrong in subquery ordering. You missed ordering by month desc. Also outer ordering should be first on year and then on month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **Edited**

```
Select A.TotalPerMonth , DateName( month , DateAdd( month , A.monthValue , -1 ) ) as month , A.Year 
from(Select Top 6 count(pk_id) as TotalPerMonth,
 month(VistorDate) as monthValue,
 Year(VistorDate) as Year 
 from jot.tbl_vistor 
 group by  month(VistorDate) ,YEAR((VistorDate))
 order by  VistorDate desc) A 
 order by A.monthValue , A.Year ASC
```

You need to specify A.monthValue DESC.  You forgot to put DESC there.

Comment: Sir , it is giving December at the top , dec , nov , oct , sep,aug,januery

Comment: That is what you want, right? You mentioned that Jan is coming at top and you want it to be last.

Comment: In the sub-query replace your  order by  YEAR((VistorDate)) desc) with ORDER BY visitordate desc and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Select A.TotalPerMonth , DateName( month, DateAdd( month , A.monthValue , -1 ) ) as month , A.Year from(
Select Top 6 count(pk_id) as TotalPerMonth, month(VistorDate) as monthValue,  Year(VistorDate) as Year 
from jot.tbl_vistor 
group by  month(VistorDate) ,YEAR((VistorDate))
order by  YEAR((VistorDate)) desc, month(VistorDate)
) A order by A.Year, A.monthValue
```

Comment: When i select Top  5 , it consider august but deleting the december

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by ordering by the complete date. To achieve this, I generated a `DATETIME` from `monthValue` and `Year`

```
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , A.monthValue , -1 ) ) as month , A.Year 
from(SELECT Top 5 
month(t.TestDate) as monthValue,
Year(t.TestDate) as Year 
from #test t 
group by  month(t.TestDate), YEAR(TestDate)
order by  month(t.TestDate), YEAR(TestDate) desc) A order BY CAST(CAST(A.monthValue AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(A.Year AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME) ASC
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: on my side it is reapeating the november month

Comment: the output on my side is oct , nov, nov , dece, jabuary

Comment: Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , A.monthValue , -1 ) ) as month , A.Year 
from(Select Top 5 
month(t.VistorDate) as monthValue,
Year(t.VistorDate) as Year 
from jot.tbl_vistor t
group by  t.VistorDate
order by  t.VistorDate desc) A order BY CAST(CAST(A.monthValue AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(A.Year AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME) ASC

Comment: I had changed the inner grouping and ordering. I edited my code, try it again.